# a question about routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url-routing, rails-routing

i want to read all records of my table . this is my code

Controller:

```
def list
    @vorlesung=Vorlesung.find(:all)
  end
```

View:

```
<html>
<body>
  <table>
     <tr>
       <th>
         Name
       </th>
     </tr>
    <% @vorlesung.each do |v| %>
     <tr>
       <td><%= v.Name %> </td>
     </tr>
    <% end %>
  </table>

</body>

</html>
```

and rout file:

```
root :to => 'vorlesungs#Show'
  match 'vorlesungs/new' =>'vorlesungs#new'
  match 'vorlesungs' =>'vorlesungs#list'
 resources :vorlesungs
```

as i understood for CRUD  i schould write only **resources :vorlesungs**. but my code doesn't work  without **match 'vorlesungs' =>'vorlesungs#list'** would you please someone tell me that reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List is not a default resource created by resources.  Check out the table in the link below to see all actions used by routes created with the resources method.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resources-on-the-web

You should either keep in your route or rename list to index (including list.html.erb in your views).  I recommend renaming list to index to avoid breaking convention.

Comment: Thank you,when i change the name of my function in controller to index and delete  match 'vorlesungs' =>'vorlesungs#list',that doesn't work and an error occured:NoMethodError ,I 'm sorry,i'm beginner :(

Answer (score 0):

The CRUD action for listing all the elements of a resource is index so if you change your code to

```
def index
    @vorlesung=Vorlesung.find(:all)
end
```

And rename your view to index then you will be able to use

```
resources :vorlesung
```